# Maven Dependency not available | Exists in local .m2 Repository | Building using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-dependency

Why is following dependency shown as missing by maven as i have added jar to local repository?

Dependency to include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hcsc.aom2</groupId>
        <artifactId>aom2-read-write-cts3-impl</artifactId>
        <version>BC20.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My Local .m2 directory has following dependency as:

[image]

Is it some kind of naming issue?

Error in Maven:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.hcsc.aom2:aom2-read-write-cts3-impl:jar:BC20.10-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Comment: It is not an error, its a warning. And it is not the dependency its it is complaining about it is the pom file of it, although I see that it is present. In some cases some artifacts of maven can get corrupted so what I usually do is to delete the folder of the dependency in the local repository an run it again forcing a clean download

Comment: @JorgeCampos: I have those jars sent by some third party and i put folders in my repository. So i could not download it from somewher.e

Comment: So then you can either install the dependency into your local repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/460557 or create a local repository and use it in your pom file: https://sookocheff.com/post/java/local-maven-repository/ or you can just point to the file in your dependency section using the file path directly using scope and system path: https://www.eviltester.com/2017/10/maven-local-dependencies.html